# Create gitlab project from template with terraform provider

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform-provider-gitlab

I want to crate a gitlab project from a template via terafrom code.

```
resource "gitlab_project" "services_projects" {
  for_each = local.service_projects
  name                            = "${each.key}"
  default_branch                  = "main"
  description                     = ""
  issues_enabled                  = false
  merge_requests_enabled          = false
  namespace_id                    = "${gitlab_group.services_group.id}"
  snippets_enabled                = false
  visibility_level                = "private"
  wiki_enabled                    = false
  use_custom_template             = "${each.value.use_custom_template}"
  template_project_id             = "${each.value.template_project_id}"
  group_with_project_templates_id = var.group_with_project_templates_id
}
```

This works, all my projects were crated and also the project to be created from template is created from the template. But then terraform errors with:

```
module.services["test_tf_1"].gitlab_project.services_projects["values"]: Destruction complete after 5s
75module.services["test_tf_1"].gitlab_project.services_projects["values"]: Creating...
76╷
77│ Error: error while waiting for project "values" import to finish: unexpected state 'failed', wanted target 'finished'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
78│ 
79│   with module.services["test_tf_bb_1"].gitlab_project.services_projects["values"],
80│   on modules/gitlab/main.tf line 132, in resource "gitlab_project" "services_projects":
81│  132: resource "gitlab_project" "services_projects" {
82│ 
83╵

85
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
87ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Does anyone knows where this error comes from or how I can solve it?

I think it has something to do with the missing template_link but I don't really understand the concept. Creating one does not work.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/group_project_file_template

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an issue of Gitlab itself, not your code/terraform provider.

Please see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/208452

It might be a flaky bug. In my case it helped simply to re-run the same code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33701955)